# Physical address order of Zip/City

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS to add contact items to an office365 account.
Everything works fine, just one detail is not as expected.
When I create a new contact and add e.g. the home address like this:

```
if (ewsContact.PhysicalAddresses.Contains(PhysicalAddressKey.Home) == false)
{
   ewsContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home] = new PhysicalAddressEntry();
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.HomeZip) == false)
{
   ewsContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].PostalCode = contact.HomeZip;
}
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.HomeCity) == false)
{
   ewsContact.PhysicalAddresses[PhysicalAddressKey.Home].City = contact.HomeCity;
}
```

The data is written to the contact item, but in the combined field and on the card view in Outlook the ordering of Zip and City is always the order that is used in the US - e.g. Washington 98155

As I have a lot of addresses from europe, I need the correct order - e.g. 10115 Berlin.
If I open the contact in Outlook, change the Zip code at one position and save it back, the order is saved correctly and the display in Outlook is correct.

Is there any way to have the correct order with EWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the PidLidWorkAddress property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815905.aspx which should contain the address information formatted in the locale of the client. So in EWS you need to set this using the Extended property definition eg

```
         ExtendedPropertyDefinition PidLidWorkAddress = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Address, 0x801B, MapiPropertyType.String);
         ewsContact.SetExtendedProperty(PidLidWorkAddress, AddressValue);
```